# Undefined variable: mysqli

Tags: php

I have function which is open a connection to DB and an insert function as below

**function.php**

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'db');

if($mysqli->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $mysqli->connect_error . ']');
}

function dbRowInsert($table_name, $form_data)
{
    $fields = array_keys($form_data);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$table_name." (`".implode('`,`', $fields)."`) VALUES('".implode("','", $form_data)."')";
    return $mysqli->query($sql);
}
?> `
```

But when i used the function in another file, it gave an error on line `return $mysqli->query($sql);` with error message  `Undefined variable: mysqli`, how come it undefined?

**save.php**

```
<?php

require_once '../config/db.php';

$postdata = file_get_contents('php://input');
$request = json_decode($postdata);

$table_name = $request->tablename;
$form_data_head = (array)$request->form_data_head;

//var_dump((array)$request->form_data_head);

dbRowInsert($table_name,$form_data_head);

?>`
```

Comment: You need to write - global $mysqli; in your dbRowInsert function, then it will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a global variable in a local (function) scope. You need to use a `global` statement or pass a parameter (the better option).

## With `global`:

```
function dbRowInsert($table_name, $form_data)
{
    global $mysqli; // add this
    $fields = array_keys($form_data);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$table_name." (`".implode('`,`', $fields)."`) VALUES('".implode("','", $form_data)."')";
    return $mysqli->query($sql);
}
```

## With `$mysqli` as a parameter (the better way)

I've added a parameter in this example, which is better for lots of reasons, especially testing. Doing it this way obviously means you need to adjust how you call the function.

```
function dbRowInsert($mysqli, $table_name, $form_data)
{
    $fields = array_keys($form_data);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$table_name." (`".implode('`,`', $fields)."`) VALUES('".implode("','", $form_data)."')";
    return $mysqli->query($sql);
}
```

Comment: with `$mysqli` as parameter, mean i have to separate the db connection to another file and include it in save.php, so  i can use `$mysqli` as parameter? is it that way?

Comment: @JosephGoh No, you don't necessarily have to move the connection to another file (but it is generally a good idea to separate unrelated functionality into different files). You just have to define a parameter for the function. For example, in `function foo($mysqli, $bar, $baz) {...`, the function `foo()` accepts parameters named `$mysqli`, `$bar`, and `$baz`. See the second example I gave you, above.